# How do I use the order of records in MySQL to build a relationship between child/parent records?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table ItemType, ProductID, and ProductName.

Unfortunately the order of the records is important as ItemType='SKU' is related to the ItemType='Product' above it.

I need to create a new field that associates the 'SKU' record with the 'Product' record above it. What I have is;

| ItemType | ProductID | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product | 2000 | My Product Name |
| SKU | 195 | Red |
| SKU | 207 | Blue |
| SKU | 124 | Red |
| Product | 2005 | My Other Product |
| SKU | 975 | Red |
| SKU | 127 | Blue |

What I want is;

| ItemType | Parent | ProductID | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product |  | 2000 | My Product Name |
| SKU | 2000 | 195 | Red |
| SKU | 2000 | 207 | Blue |
| SKU | 2000 | 124 | Red |
| Product |  | 2005 | My Other Product |
| SKU | 2005 | 975 | Red |
| SKU | 2005 | 127 | Blue |

Basically I am trying to use the order of the records in the table to build a relationship between parent/child.

I am working with an eCommerce product output file, and it is a dreadful format that I cannot change.

Reading around I think I have to use cursors in MySQL to achieve what I want but I have never used them before.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: That's a no can do. Tables represent relations, which are a special case of sets and as sets have no intrinsic order, relations don't and tables don't too. There can be a combination of columns that define an order of course but you don't seem to have such. Needless to say, your design is simply wrong for a relational database.

Comment: Is ProductID unique in this table? Please provide the full table declaration. Why can the `output file` format not be updated? What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please note that this may not be 100% reliable as the order in which rows is returned should not be relied upon. It worked in my test case. It would be much better, and safer, to push for the output file format of the eCommerce product to be updated or to get read only access to the data so you can export it yourself.

I created a table `items` based on your example above -

```sql
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `ItemType` ENUM('Product', 'SKU') NOT NULL,
    `ProductID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `ProductName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `items` VALUES
    ('Product', 2000, 'My Product Name'),
    ('SKU', 195, 'Red'),
    ('SKU', 207, 'Blue'),
    ('SKU', 124, 'Red'),
    ('Product', 2005, 'My Other Product'),
    ('SKU', 975, 'Red'),
    ('SKU', 127, 'Blue');
```

It is really important that `ProductID` is not set as the PK at this point, as it would cause the rows to be re-ordered by `ProductID`.

Add the new `Parent` column -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `items`
    ADD COLUMN `Parent` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL AFTER `ItemType`;
```

You can create a query to track the current ProductID using a user variable -

```sql
SELECT
    `ProductID`,
    IF(`ItemType` = 'Product', @cur_ID := `ProductID`, NULL) AS `cur_parent_id`,
    IF(`ItemType` = 'SKU', @cur_ID, NULL) AS `parent_id`
FROM `items`, (SELECT @cur_ID := NULL) `p`
```

Then use the following query to update the `Parent` column -

```sql
UPDATE `items`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `ProductID`,
        IF(`ItemType` = 'Product', @cur_ID := `ProductID`, NULL) AS `cur_parent_id`,
        IF(`ItemType` = 'SKU', @cur_ID, NULL) AS `parent_id`
    FROM `items`, (SELECT @cur_ID := NULL) `p`
) t ON `items`.`ProductID` = `t`.`ProductID`
SET `items`.`Parent` = `t`.`parent_id`;
```

Comment: Excellent solution, works perfectly. I had no idea you could include variables in this way. Very useful for the future.

Comment: Setting variables in expressions like this is now deprecated functionality and will probably be removed in the next major version. Glad it helped.

Comment: Good to know. Is the alternative solution to use a cursor to step through the table using a variable to record last record in the same way? I know this is fighting the whole concept of a relational database, but many of the big eCommerce platforms export files by default that rely on the sequence of records for relationships. Horrible, but true.

Comment: I don't want to resort to Excel Macros to do the same thing.

Comment: How did you get the data into your table in the first instance? I would suggest writing a simple parser in your language of choice. I would have thought that most eCommerce systems would have an API that would allow access to this sort of data.